# Django and angularjs storing api templates

Tags: django, angularjs

I am trying to build an angularjs, django application... I have seen examples that sores the templates in static folder. Do you think that is a good practice?

Django has template folders for visual stuff.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. From the point of view of Django, AngularJS templates are static files. If you try to serve them as templates, then Django will attempt to parse the template syntax and all kinds of odd things will happen.